# Show that $\dfrac{\mathbb Z[x]}{(2,x)}$ is a field.

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification

> Show that $\dfrac{\mathbb Z[x]}{(2,x)}$ is a field, where $$(2,x)=\{p(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]:\text{the constant term of $p(x)$ is even}\}$$

Thus $\dfrac{\mathbb Z[x]}{(2,x)}=\{(2,x),1+(2,x)\}.$ Since $\{(2,x),1+(2,x)\}$ has no divisor of zero it's a finite integral domain and hence a field.

Please tell me if I made it correct?

Comment: I see this is enough reason to conclude it as a field.... well done :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Thanks sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! That's fine that you applied the lemma about finite commutative domains.

Another way to see it is to use isomorphism theorems to reformulate the ring. I'm thinking specifically of the one that says $(R/J)/(I/J)\cong R/I$.

Applying this in your case, $\Bbb Z[x]/(2,x)\cong (\Bbb Z[x]/(x))/(x,2)/(x)\cong \Bbb Z/(2)$, which is the field of two elements.